# Better and also concise way to write a query..(Mysql + C language)

Tags: mysql, c

Is there a more concise way to write the following query (using Mysql + C ):

```
 memset(query, 0, 200);
            strcat(query, "UPDATE Sconti SET ");
            strcat(query, "Sconto = '");
            strcat(query, nuovo_sconto);
            strcat(query, "' WHERE For_Sconti ='");
            strcat(query, For_Sconti);
            strcat(query, "' AND Cat_Sconti='");
            strcat(query, Cat_Sconti);
            strcat(query, "';");

            if (mysql_query (conn, query)) {
                        printf("\nErrore query:\n");
                printf("%s", mysql_error(conn),"\n");
```

The problem is that if I have to update a table having 12 fields, things get annoying..

Thanks, Vera

Comment: The first thing to worry about is that this code is open to [SQL injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) attacks.

Comment: A classic example of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm

Comment: It's just school project..so I shouldn't worry about...but thanks a lot for your suggestion..This makes me feel eager to know how I can modify the code in oder to make it more concise and especially safer ..What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the version of MySQL you are using, you can use prepared statements.  Check out chapter 20.9 of the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c.html).

With prepared statements you can setup a query like this:
`char *queryText = "Update Sconti set Sconto = ? where for_sconti = ? and cat_sconti = ?";`

Answer (score 2):

```
char string[512];

//code to clean the string :)
sprintf(string,"UPDATE Sconti SET Sconto = '%f' WHERE For_Sconti ='%f' AND Cat_Sconti='%f';",scontoValue,forScontiValue,catScontiValue);
```

Search for sprintf in this page:

http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can use `sprintf` and do something like ...

```
sprintf(query, "UPDATE Sconti Set "
   " Sconto = '%s'"
   "WHERE FOR_Sconti = '%s'|
   /* etc .... */
   ";", nuove_sconto, For_Sconti, Cat_Sconti);
```

Note I use a C trick that in C `"a""b"` is equivalent to `"ab"` and so equivalet to

```
"a"
"b"
```

Answer (score 1):

always sprintf

it's a glorous function that act as a printf but write over a string istead of writing over the standard output.
It's very simple to use by everybody since there is no c developer which does not know printf since his first hello world!
Adapring it to your code would look like:

```
char yourString[512];
sprintf(yourString,"UPDATE Sconti SET Sconto = '%f' WHERE For_Sconti ='%f' AND Cat_Sconti='%f';",nuovo_sconto,For_Sconti,Cat_Sconti);
```

Cheers,